# Shortcut to run a Julia file in JuliaPro on Windows 10 (or how to set Ctrl-Enter as a shortcut to run file)?

Tags: julia

How do I run a Julia file from the script editor pane in JuliaPro (on Windows 10)?

The `keymap.cson` file was blank when I opened it via File > Keymap... in JuliaPro. I added

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="source julia"]':
 'ctrl-enter': 'julia-client:run-file'
```

Pressing `Ctrl+Enter` in the script/file editor pane seems to not do anything. I can run the file via Julia > Run all. I have closed and reopened JuliaPro since editing the `keymap.cson` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the `keymap.cson` to

```
'atom-text-editor':
 'ctrl-enter': 'julia-client:run-all'
```

and the file runs when I press `Ctrl+Enter` from within it, which was the (MATLAB-esque) behaviour I was seeking.

Leaving this here because I guessed `run-all` on a whim and didn't find this information online within 15 minutes of searching.

Comment: Also note that the default shortcut for this is `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`. You can get an overview over which keybindings are assigned by going to `Settings > Keybindings` and filtering by `julia` (and/or `juno`).